# Color lookup with a matplotlib colormap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to look up the RGB values for arbitrary numbers from a colormap.

Assume I have a colormap `'spring'`

```
from matplotlib import cm

c = cm.get_cmap('spring')
```

And now suppose I have a value from `0` to `1`, I want to pluck the RGB values from `c`

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3, 1415])
v = np.random.rand(1)

v

0.4449393091533107
```

How do map that to get the corresponding RGB?

If I look at

```
c._segmentdata

{'blue': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
 'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
 'red': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))}
```

... I'm at a loss as to what to do.

I've looked up this link https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html

But this tells me how to do it for a whole 2d matrix.

Comment: @wwii we usually give people a few minutes (-:

Comment: I was wondering if you were testing *us*.

Comment: That is something I would do. But not this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand what you're asking, you can do the following:

```
c(v[0])
```

This will give you the following `RGBA` array:

```
(1.0, 0.44313725490196076, 0.55686274509803924, 1.0)
```

So if you just want the `RGB`, you can just index it as necessary:

```
>>> c(v[0])[:3]
(1.0, 0.44313725490196076, 0.55686274509803924)
```

More info in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap)

Comment: .. In OP's question, `v` is a scalar.

Comment: Following OP's setup routine, I ended up with `type(v)` as `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`, but the same strategy works for a scalar, of course (`c(0.4449393091533107)` gives the same results)

Comment: Frustrated that it was so easy. But equally grateful that I asked instead of thrashing about the internet any longer.

Comment: Thats the beauty of SO! Glad I could help (I actually struggled with something very similar just a couple weeks ago)